# Prevent data corruption

Tags: linux, database, sqlite, corruption, wal

I'm working on an Embedded linux running on ARM9.
The filesystem is ext4 type (rw, sync, noatime, data=writeback)
I implemented a process that writes/reads to a SQLite3 database in a Write-Ahead-Loggin (WAL) mode, with unsync enabled. When a powerloss is happening, I have around two seconds to save all data by syncing and checkpointing the DB. But, still, I see that sometimes the DB is being corrupted which is really not good in my case.

I would like to write a new DB engine for my purpose, In a similar way to SQLite, where the DB will be hold in one file. But in this case, I'm thinking of writing the header data to one sector and the rest of the data at least two sectors after , so the size of the DB will be larger but when writing the data, It will not ruin the header of the file, which holds the indexes and etc.  That way, only the last data will be corrupted and not all the file, as SQLite behaves.

My question is if my approach is right?

Comment: Implementing your own DB engine sounds like overkill to me. Data consistency should be provided by all serious DB systems, including SQLite. You don't mention details about the file system and hardware you're using and its configuration (journalling, write cache etc.). Maybe you should look for the actual problem with your current setup first?

Comment: I updated my question - provided some filesystem info. Maybe it is overkill but I have to build a robust DB. The difference is that when data is corrupted in my design, the header (written only once at the creation of the DB file) which holds meta data won't be corrupted and therefore, the DB will be still be readable.

Comment: Why are you checkpointing the DB? Don't. Anyway, if you are using some flash storage that corrupts *unrelated* sectors when some write is going on during power loss, there is not much you can do.

Comment: Yes, I'm using an SD card, and The problem is with SQLite is that when the data is corrupted, I can't read nothing from the DB and all the DB is lost (And not just the latest data that has been written). Moreover, I start checkpoint manually whenever the unit sense power down.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ping pong technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping-pong_scheme).

In ping pong technique you use 2 separate files and write alternatively to one and another. If a power loss occurs in the worst case you have at most 1 single corrupted file and you can safely use the other one. In the best case none of them is corrupted and you can continue using the latest one.

A corrupted file is easily detected if you use hashing functions or other CRC schemes

Obviously this scheme doesn't save you from write-cache or other disk caching mechanism which could be working under the hood.

Alternatively, you can use a journaled file system which features data integrity protection on it's own

Be aware that ping-pong and journaling schemes ensure only data integrity. Data loss could still occur. Data integrity and data loss are two completely different things

Comment: The thing is, If I write the data to the file on a sector that is not even near the header that contains the indexes and the meta-data of the DB file, why should data loss should ever occur? I never write to the header, and therefore the only data i can lose is the latest data that has been added to the DB file.

Comment: that's fine as long you have a strong way to discriminate "correct" data from partial data. A block could be partially written on disk even if your system has 2 seconds before shut down entirely. You must reject partial blocks therefore you need a way to detect them

Comment: Yes, Every block of data that is being written to the file is check-summed and the signature is added to its end.